# How can I check which process uses the microphone at a given moment?

Tags: c#, windows, microphone

Is there a possibility to check which process uses the microphone at a given moment? For example whether Skype is using the computer microphone at a given moment?

Also connected to this:

Can I access the event when the mic starts to listen for Voice?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do this, using **Network Watcher**.
(Something like FileSystemWatcher)
So you can check the connectivity of an indicated IP and be aware when it connected to your system. (Create an event in this way)

This article may be helpful :
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/225747/NET-Network-Monitor